# Loss functions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, loss, interpretation

I want to know how to interpret the loss functions results in MATLAB?

On other words, for example if I got 0.3247 as a results of kfoldLoss() function, is this mean that it is 32.47% error or it is a 0.3247%, or how correctly can I define/interpret this obtained result?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Is it the mean squared error and is likely returned as simply a decimal, so it would be equivalent to 32.47%

Comment: 32.47% is correct

Comment: I guessed so, but there are results in the help of MATLAB of the kfoldloss() function such as 44.9635 where L = kfoldLoss(cvmodel,'mode','individual'). So, if we supposed that the output of my question will be 32.47%, then, how can we interpret 44.9635?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the mean of the errors across your k folds was 32.47%.